# Looping a creation based on user input

Tags: ruby, algorithm, function, irb

I'm creating an algorithm to sort cups by the length of their radii. The input would be

```
2  
red 10       
green 7
```

and the output being

```
green
red
```

My approach to this is seeing as the first input is 2 I would have to create 2 Cup that have colour and radius attributes. As seen here:

```
class Cup
    attr_accessor :colour, :radius

    def initialize(colour, radius)
        @colour = ""
        @radius = 0
    end

    def number_of_cups
        puts "How many cups are there?".chomp
        gets.times do 
            Cup.new("", 0)
        end
    end
end
```

I am receiving an `undefined method` error when I try to access Cup.number_of_cups. My question is, for example, if I typed in `3` then I would have `3` new cup objects?

Comment: Calling `chomp` on hardcoded string makes zero sense. Also, `gets` receives a string back, hence do `gets.to_i.times`. Also please next time post the whole error message.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right. Thanks for the help! Although now the cups aren't actually being created the loop is acting as a false positive. When I type Cup.all I get the error 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /Users/WTFwerewolf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):3
NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for Cup:Class)`

Comment: Which is probably because (surprise) the class `Cup` has no method `all` defined? There is no magic.

Comment: Ahh I thought `all` was something Ruby understood automatically. Has worked in the Rails console before. Will be working on separating the next input lines. Thanks for your help though I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear basic with ruby

```
class Cup
    attr_accessor :colour, :radius

    def initialize(colour='No Colour', radius=0)
        @colour = colour
        @radius = radius
    end
end

puts "How many cups are there?"
cups = []
gets.to_i.times do |n| 
  puts "Enter Cup-#{n+1} colour & radius:"
  c = gets.chomp
  r = gets.to_i
  cups << Cup.new(c, r)
end

sorted_cups = cups.sort_by { |x| x.radius }
```

Further you can display sorted_cups